# CSS Select a 2nd descendant

Tags: css

I'm using Chrome Debugging tool to find elements on a page. I am having trouble understanding the logic. 
The piece of HTML looks like this

Here is my first solution [image: firstVariant]

It is a menu where I'm trying to select a second link for "Logout". But it doesn't recognize "a" as descendant of a "div".

But when I select it, a child of an element which is descendant of a "div" it finds it

Can someone explain why I cannot find it when I do it as on the first picture

[image: secondVariant]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on MDN Web Docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

> The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.

Clearly here the `<a>` is not being siblings of each other, so your selector is not correct on the first image.

Though the second selector of yours is correct as `<li>` are siblings.

Answer (score 3):

`a:nth-child(2)` matches an `<a>` element that's the second child of its immediate parent. But each `<li>` only has one child, there's never a second child. It's the `<ul>` elements that have multiple `<li>` children, so you need to put the `:nth-child` modifier on `li`, and then select the `<a>` within that.

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-child()` pseudo-class only selects elements that are the nth-child of their direct parent, it doesn't work for an arbitrarily high ancestor.

The reason it does not work in your first solution is because each `a` is the *first* child of its parent (`li`). Since each `a` is the first child, `:nth-child(2)` won't select any `a`.

The reason it works in your second solution is because you are selecting the second `li`. The parent of `li` is `ul`, and `ul` has two `li` elements in it, so `li:nth-child(2)` is able to find the second `li`.